# Why are my test files not being transpiled?

Tags: jestjs

I have a suite of tests are being run with `jest`.

```
  - initFromProgressObject.test.js
  - nodeifyProgressObject.test.js
  - segments.test.js
  - uuid.test.js
  - volume.progress.test.js
  - volume.segment.test.js
```

The command i use to run the tests is `jest --notify`.  Here is the error I get in just 2 of the files:

```
/Users/bob/Developer/sedd/sedd-utils/src/tests/uuid.test.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import * as uuid from "../utils/uuid";
                                                                                             ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

All of the files are using `import`, but only 2 of them are having this issue of `Unexpected token import`.  On another question, I saw that it was important to set the `env` to `test`.  I have tried that and it didn't change anything.

Here is my `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "env": {
    "es": {
      "presets": [
        [
          "env",
          {
            "targets": {
              "browsers": ["last 2 versions"],
              "node": "current"
            },
            "modules": false
          }
        ]
      ],
      "ignore": ["**/*.test.js", "**/tests/*"]
    },
    "test": {
      "presets": ["env"]
    },
    "cjs": {
      "presets": [
        [
          "env",
          {
            "targets": {
              "browsers": ["last 2 versions"],
              "node": "current"
            }
          }
        ]
      ],
      "ignore": ["**/*.test.js", "**/tests/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

The jest config is just the default.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does your jest config and `.babelrc` file looks.